# retrive data from drupal not working

Tags: database

**What I tried**

```
    $sql="select * from project_status where node_id=".$vid." and ".  strtolower($field_progress_flags)."!='' and ".  strtolower($field_progress_flags)." IS NOT NULL";    
    $query=$sql;
    $array = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($object = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = $object;
    }
    mysql_freeresult($result);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
```

the actual sql query is  `select * from project_status where node_id=385 and draft!='' and draft IS NOT NULL`

here am not getting any data
what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D got the solution as follows:

```
$sql="select * from project_status where node_id=".$vid." and ".  strtolower($field_progress_flags)."!='' and ".  strtolower($field_progress_flags)." IS NOT NULL";    
$result = db_query($sql);
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()){
        $data[]=$record;
}
```

and its works for me